# Extract rows having a [maximum / minimum] on a certain column grouped by another column

Tags: matlab

I would like to extract rows having a maximum value on `col3` and grouped by `col2`.

So for example if I have:

```
%    col1  col2  col3
M = [112   1     78
     112   2     2
     120   2     77
     101   1     86
     112   3     103]
```

The result of `MAX on col3 GROUP BY col2` would be (the row order doesn't matter):

```
%    col1  col2  col3
R = [120   2     77
     101   1     86
     112   3     103]
```

Actually I'm using:

```
M       = sortrows(M,[2,3])
[~,ind] = unique(M(:,2),'last')
R       = M(ind,:)
```

But I found this solution overcomplicated, have you a simpler solution ? I would like to avoid using a matlab `table`.

Comment: Did any of the two solutions work you?

Comment: Yes, both works actually, but I always wait a few days to get as many answer as possible and then select the (IMO) best solution. I will add a benchmark and accept the fastest solution, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be faster but seems more complicated than the original solution:

```
function out = getmax (x)
    [~, out] = max (x);
end

idx = accumarray(M(:,2), 1:size(M,1), [], @(x) x(getmax(M(x,3))));
R = M(idx, :);
```

EDIT:
Note that if values in `M(:,2)` don't form a permutation of a continuous range of positive integers starting from `1` (and possibly with repetition) they should be transformed by `unique`.

```
[~, ~, col2] = unique (M(:,2));
idx = accumarray(col2, 1:size(M,1), [], @(x) x(getmax(M(x,3))));
R = M(idx, :);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [findgroups](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findgroups.html) and [splitapply](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html):

```
>> G = findgroups(M(:,2));
>> Y = arrayfun(@(x) find(M(:,3)==x),splitapply(@max,M(:,3),G));
>> M(Y,:)

ans =

   101     1    86
   120     2    77
   112     3   103
```